# JS Puppeteer - async, scraping - Functions outside puppeteer async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, async-await, puppeteer

First, I load the span elements, which I have to click on to display the html code.

Then, in the processMatch method, I first create div.eventTable, which is the wrapping element, and then extract the text value from it. The program is simple overall, but it is inconsistent, as it sometimes crashes or loads only a few elements.

The site I'm scraping https://www.tipsport.cz/kurzy/fotbal/fotbal-muzi/evropska-liga-kvalifikace-88589. After clicking on the match, the elements appear and I want to see the name of the bet and the value of the odds.

EDIT: I don't know if I am using async correctly and there is some conflict when calling. The program loads a few items, but then crashes.

All program: https://codepen.io/aaron1799/pen/NWeNrMa

All program try-catch: https://codepen.io/aaron1799/pen/WNLwxJX

```
async function getElementsInArray(page, element) {
    await page.waitForSelector(element);
    const elemArray = await page.$$(element);
    return elemArray;
}

async function getItem(item) {
    let itemText = await item.evaluate((el) => el.textContent);
    return itemText.trim();
}

async function getOdds(bets, odds, betCategory) {
    let arr = [];
    let trimmedbetCategory = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < bets.length; i++) {
        let trimmedBet = "";
        let trimmedOdd = "";

        if (bets[i]) trimmedBet = await getItem(bets[i]);
        if (odds[i]) trimmedOdd = await getItem(odds[i]);
        if (betCategory[i]) trimmedbetCategory = await getItem(betCategory[i]);

        const bet = {
            event: trimmedbetCategory,
            bet: trimmedBet,
            odd: trimmedOdd,
        };

        arr.push(bet);
    }

    return arr;
}

async function processMatch(page) {
    await page.waitForSelector("div.eventTable");
    let events = await getElementsInArray(page, "div.eventTable"); // obalovaci tabulky
    let arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        let betCategory = await getElementsInArray(events[i], "div.name");
        let bets = await getElementsInArray(
            events[i],
            "span.name > .cropped-text-100"
        );
        let odds = await getElementsInArray(events[i], "span.value");

        let betsMatch = await getOdds(bets, odds, betCategory);
        arr.push(betsMatch);
    }

    return arr;
}



(async () => {
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_PAGE,
        maxConcurrency: 100,
        puppeteerOptions: {
            timeout: 40000000,
            retryLimit: 5,
            defaultViewport: false,
            userDataDir: "./tmp",
            headless: false,
        },
    });

    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
        let allBets = [];

        await page.goto(url);

        const spanElementsForClick = await getElementsInArray(
            page,
            "div.o-matchRow__leftSide > div > div.o-matchRow__colEvent > span > span"
        );

        for (const span of spanElementsForClick) {
            await span.click();

            let match = await processMatch(page);
            allBets.push(match);
        }

    });

  
})();
```

EDIT 2:
I get this error when trying try blocks, could it be caused by a browser crash?

```
Error in getElementsInArray: TargetCloseError: Protocol error (DOM.describeNode): Target closed
    at CallbackRegistry.clear (C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:138:36)
    at CDPSessionImpl._onClosed (C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:468:25)
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:248:25)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\NodeWebSocketTransport.js:53:36)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
Error in processMatch: TargetCloseError: Protocol error (DOM.describeNode): Target closed
    at CallbackRegistry.clear (C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:138:36)
    at CDPSessionImpl._onClosed (C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:468:25)
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:248:25)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\NodeWebSocketTransport.js:53:36)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
```

Comment: What's the question, exactly? Can you show the exact output you expect?

Comment: @ggorlen I don't know if I am using async correctly and there is some conflict when calling. The program loads a few items, but then crashes.

Comment: Maybe I'm making some basic mistake with puppeteer that I'm not aware of, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your code looks technically OK, but using element handles like this can be brittle. I'd suggest using `$$eval` and collecting all text contents in one operation, rather than breaking it up into a `$$` followed by many different `evaluate` calls on each specific handle. That's slow and if the page changes from the time you select the handles to when you try to pull the text out, that could cause problems. Long selectors like `foo > bar > baz > quux` are [also brittle](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors).

Comment: It's also better to not use "parallel" arrays like this--better to use a nested, container-based scrape. Start with whatever element most closely wraps all 3 child elements, then loop over that and pull out children. 40000000 is 11 hours, a rather excessive timeout. I'd make that shorter so you can actually see problems instead of suppressing them. I'll add an answer if you don't mind sharing your expected output and I have time.

Comment: @ggorlen So, if I understand correctly, at the place of the getElementsInArray call, it should pull the text strings straight away and work with them. Those selectors look clearer to me this way, and they shouldn't lead to a collision anywhere on the page. And the problem will probably be "overloading" the browser